# node.js processes with the same name in forever are closed when trying to close only one

Tags: node.js, forever

I am deploying two node.js apps on the aws, the two apps are in the paths shown as

```
/home/ubuntu/nodes/app1/app.js
/home/ubuntu/nodes/app2/app.js
```

respectively

to run the node.js apps in the background, I used forever to start two apps, so like

```
   $ sudo forever start /home/ubuntu/nodes/app1/app.js
   $ sudo forever start /home/ubuntu/nodes/app2/app.js
```

so forever works well by running the two node.js apps in the background process.
However, when I tried to stop one process with forever command like this.

```
   $ sudo forever stop /home/ubuntu/nodes/app1/app.js
```

unexpectedly, both node.js process are closed with info like this

```
info:    Forever stopped process:
data:        uid  command         script forever pid   logfile                 uptime
[0] r2pZ /usr/bin/nodejs app.js 24852   24854 /root/.forever/r2pZ.log 0:0:1:14.775
[1] 9f2h /usr/bin/nodejs app.js 24870   24872 /root/.forever/9f2h.log 0:0:0:58.733
```

I assume it is because two node.js process has the same name - app.js, how to avoid this by close only one process

Comment: See [this two month old issue](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/481).

Comment: same issue. But still no one to solve it ?

Comment: Apparently not :( Perhaps look at a different process manager? I like [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) myself, although I can't guarantee it doesn't suffer from similar (or other) issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can kill only one process using the index of the process shown in the `forever list` command. For example, if you type `forever stop 1`, only the process with the index 1 will be killed

Comment: But you couldn't distinguish these scripts by `forever list` because this command doesn't show the path of script.

Comment: @Chang you can see path to the script by running command `forever columns add dir` which will add dir column in forever listing

Answer (score 49):

You can use an uid (see [here](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever#command-line-usage)):

```
$ sudo forever --uid "app1" start app.js
$ sudo forever --uid "app2" start app.js
```

And to stop:

```
$ sudo forever stop app1
```

**Update**
The `--uid` option is deprecated. 
Now you can use the `--pidFile` option. Example:

```
forever start --pidFile /some/path/app1.pid app.js
forever start --pidFile /some/path/app2.pid app.js
```

And to stop:

```
forever stop --pidFile /some/path/app1.pid
```

Comment: to use --pidFile, an actual pid file must exists. But what is a pid file? what it's content? I'm can't find anything related online, and forever docs don't state.

Comment: A PID file is just a file with a process number in it. So, I'm assuming that when forever "stop" a pidFile, it is killing that process number. When you run `forever start` with the --pidFile option, forever should create the pid file for you

Comment: I have been testing but no luck. I couldn't understand how it works. I tried to start with --pidFile and existing pid file as you said, but it didn't do anything different. I tried with a not existing pid file, but this one wasn't created and forever run indifferently. So I will continue to use --uid because deprecated and working is better to not do anything:)