# How to stop a forever process knowing the name

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a node script in which I need to stop a forever process, before uploading the new version and restart it again;

the problem is that I only know the name of that process, and

```
forever stop processName.js
```

doesn't work, since it expect the index or the uid;
is it possible to stop it knowing only the name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got it, using a variable:

```
uid=$(forever list | grep processName.js | cut -c24-27) && forever stop $uid
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23836822/2885826) also works and it is from forever itself. And the `--uuid` option is not deprecated

Comment: It works nicely. The only disadventage is that if you have two processes with processName.js it wont kill any of these.

Answer (score 3):

```
forever stop /home/user/server/script.js (full path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign a unique id for the process while starting it, and then can close it using this. It looks for existing process by `uid`, and stops it, if it is running. Then it will start forever again with the same unique name.

```
if forever list | grep 'my-unique-process'; then forever stop my-unique-process; fi
forever -a --uid my-unique-process start app.js
```

**Explanation**:

If the process is running, then close it. If you close it while it's not running, it will throw an error

```
Forever cannot find process with id
```

The first line looks for the output of `forever list` command and matches the process name. Simple if-else of shell.

In the second line, the `-a` will append to the log. If you don't use `-a`, it sometimes gives error that 'Log file already exist'

`--uid` is used to assign a unique id to the process.

Comment: worth noting, that --uid do not work for option logs: `forever --uid my-unique-process logs`